# How to revert back to the older WordPress version?

Tags: wordpress

I have updated the latest WordPress 4.1. Now my site just doesn't work due to the plugins being incompatible. I know the plugin is probalby too old but I want to go back to the older WP version 3.9 until I have more time to looking for a more perm solution. How can I do that?

Comment: Live and learn, buddy. Always audit your site before upgrading. Always backup your site before upgrading. Always test locally and/or on a test server before making updates live.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you can roll back to a previous version (unless you have a backup of the database). It's also ill-advised; updating WP is important for security. Trying to roll back WP to maintain compatibility is a bad idea because: 1. It exposes you to potential vulnerabilities in the core and 2. It means you're running really old plugins that could also have vulnerabilities. 
There is an outside chance that the plugin(s) could be made compatible/replaced/updatd. Which plugins are causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks. It's the Timely calendar plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me for being the bearer of news you do not wish to hear, there is never an "easy" way to do that. You SHOULD backup of your database BEFORE the upgrade then you would be table to do an reinstall without losing any data. If you didn't, you simply cannot go back but to upgrade the broken plugin.